# Select Based on Multiple Conditions

Tags: mysql

If we have two tables like this

```
CREATE TABLE ta(`ID` int, `name` char(10));
INSERT INTO ta (`ID`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'A'),
    (2, 'A'),
    (3, 'B'),
    (4, 'C'),
    (5, 'B');

CREATE TABLE yourtable(`ID` int, `Val` int);
INSERT INTO yourtable (`ID`, `Val`)
VALUES
    (1, 10),
    (1, 20),
    (1, 30),
    (1, 30),
    (2, 10),
    (2, 20),
    (3, 20),
    (3, 20),
    (4, 10),
    (4, 20),    
    (5, 10),
    (5, 20),
    (5, 30);
```

And, I need to group the values by `name` using two tables. And, for condition val=10 OR val=30 it works fine. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c099/1

```
select name, count(distinct t1.id)
from yourtable as t1, ta
where t1.id=ta.id
AND (val=10 OR val=30)
group by name
```

But, for the condition **(val=10 AND val!=30)** how do I query it?
for which,output should be

```
   Count
A  1
B  0
C  1
```

Here's an example: Take the case of name=A, here we get ID=1,2. So, now in table yourtable we have 5 rows with ID=1,2. For ID=1, val=10,20,20. And for ID=2, val=10,20. Here only ID=2 satisfies (val=10 AND val!=30) So,for name=A count=1

Comment: Strange condition. If val=10 it can not be equal to 30, so second part of condition has no sence

Comment: Also your desired result does not match the condition. There are 2 A's 1 B and 1 C for val=10.

Comment: Here's an example: Take the case of name=A, here we get ID=1,2. So, now in table yourtable we have 5 rows with ID=1,2. For ID=1, val=10,20,20. And for ID=2, val=10,20. Here only ID=2 satisfies (val=10 AND val!=30) So,for name=A count=1

Comment: It makes perfect sense to me!

Comment: Hm, without some PRIMARY KEYs it might difficult to provide a definitive solution.

Comment: The condition seems to be relating to the set of Val's for that ID, rather than a row with a ID, Val pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ta.name
     , COUNT(DISTINCT t2.val)
  FROM yourtable t1 
  LEFT
  JOIN yourtable t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id 
   AND t2.val IN (30) -- <-- things to exclude
  LEFT
  JOIN ta 
    ON ta.id = t1.id 
 WHERE t1.val IN (10) -- <-- things to include
 GROUP
    BY name;

NAME COUNT(T2.VAL)
A    1
B    1
C    0
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c099/169

Comment: You're missing printing the empty ones with 0.

Comment: Now the result does not match

Comment: Mmm nope, B is 0 and C is 1

Comment: Indeed B is 0 going by he bottom information since there is no B id with val 10 and no val 30, C does have 1 and A does have 1 so his output seem right going by his logic. From what I understood he wants to pick the ID only if that given id does not contain the number 30 and does contain the number 10.

Answer (score 0):

You want a subquery on `yourtable` that determines whether an ID satisfies the condition, and join that to `ta`

```
select name, SUM(Satisfies)
from ta, (
    SELECT distinct ID, CASE WHEN ID NOT IN (
        SELECT ID FROM yourtable
        WHERE Val = 30 )
    AND ID IN (
        SELECT ID FROM yourtable
        WHERE Val = 10 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Satisfies
    FROM yourtable
) t1
WHERE t1.id=ta.id
group by name
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a11d6/29)

Comment: with your UPDATE it now does but with your last fiddle it was not doing it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a11d6/23

Comment: That would probably be me not knowing exactly how sqlfiddle works, it seems if you run only part of the query the URL it gives only has that part

Answer (score 0):

Not really nice but working:

```
SELECT name, max(occ) occurencies
  FROM (SELECT name, count(distinct t1.id) as occ
          FROM yourtable as t1, ta
         WHERE t1.id=ta.id
           AND val=10 
           AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT name 
                             FROM yourtable as t2 
                            WHERE t2.id=ta.id AND t2.val=30)
        GROUP BY name
        UNION
        SELECT name, 0 as occ
          FROM yourtable as t1, ta
         WHERE t1.id=ta.id
           AND val=10 
           AND EXISTS (SELECT name 
                         FROM yourtable as t2 
                        WHERE t2.id=ta.id AND t2.val=30)) as base
 GROUP BY name;
```

Check out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c099/192

**p.s.**: slightly nicer:

```
 SELECT ta.name, COALESCE (occ, 0)
   FROM ta
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT name, count(distinct t1.id) as occ
                FROM yourtable as t1, ta
               WHERE t1.id=ta.id
                 AND val=10 
                 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT name 
                                   FROM yourtable as t2 
                                  WHERE t2.id=ta.id 
                                    AND t2.val=30)
               GROUP BY name) AS base ON (base.name = ta.name)
  GROUP BY name;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c099/212

:)